# TypeError: 'application/json' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to import a JSON file into a JavaScript with the following statement

```js
import phone_numbers from "./phoneNumbers.json";
```

The JavaScript file is loaded as a module into my HTML file like this

```html
<script type="module" src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
```

When I view The page, I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'application/json' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I have tried importing it like this

```js
import phone_numbers from "./phoneNumbers.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

but I get the following error then

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'assert'. Expected a ';' following a targeted import declaration.
```

How can I import a json file into a JavaScript file correctly

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which environment(s) did you receive the errors?

Answer (score 3):

There are four basic options.

## Use Node.js and CommonJS

```
const phone_numbers = require("./phoneNumbers.json");
```

Since you are working with a browser, this isn't an option for you.

## Use JSON modules

You'll need something that supports [the proposed JSON module specification](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules) such as [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules) and the correct syntax:

```
import phone_numbers from "./phoneNumbers.json" assert { type: 'json' };
```

## Preprocess the JSON

Tools like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can process an `import ... .json'` statement and bundle the JSON into an app.

## Use Ajax instead

```
const response = await fetch("/url/to/phoneNumbers.json");
const phone_numbers = await response.json();
```

You'll need to use something that supports top-level `await` or move the code inside an `async` function.

Comment: better written and more complete than mine - have my upvote ^^

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just import a JSON file as JS, but instead have to load it from the server manually with your JS code - using something like [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp) or the newer [`fetch`-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Many web frameworks have specialized HTTP clients included for that, using framework features - so if you use a framework, look at what they give you.